# Turning a list of characters that contain numbers into integers in R

Tags: r

Is there a faster way in R to turn a list of characters like `c("12313","21323")` into an integer list like `c(12313, 21323)` other than writing a for loop myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `as.*` functions are already vectorized:

```
R> txt <- c("123456", "7890123")
R> as.numeric(txt)
[1]  123456 7890123
R> sum(as.numeric(txt))
[1] 8013579
R>
```

In general, 'thinking vectorized' is the way to go with R, but it takes some practice.